# Pycharm debuger disconects

Tags: python, pycharm, python-itertools

Hi I have list of four directions and method like

```
directions = ["NORTH", "EAST", "SOUTH", "WEST"]
def rotate_left(self):
    cycled = cycle(self.directions)
    current = dropwhile(lambda x: x != self.direction, cycled)
    self.direction = next(current)
```

but somehow after this method my program stops without any exception

any idea why?
Thanks

Comment: Write a complete example that reproduces your issue

Comment: I just call this method an it seems like process cycles at last statement

Comment: How are you calling `rotate_left`?

Comment: As it is your code is not runnable

Comment: Its a method of a class robot.rotate_left()

Comment: What is the initial value of `self.direction`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that problem was that dropwhile() condition could never come true in my code. Due to pythons lazy execution it seemed that problem was with me calling next(), but it was only because that was when dropwhile() executed, causing it to cycle thru endless List without ever completing condition.

Sorry for wasting your time everybody.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to repeat the description of your issue with the following code

```
from itertools import cycle, dropwhile

direction = None
directions = ["NORTH", "EAST", "SOUTH", "WEST"]
cycled = cycle(directions)
current = dropwhile(lambda x: x != direction, cycled)
direction = next(current)
```

It's difficult to say without the rest of your code, but by the looks of, the initial value of `direction` does not exist in the `directions` list; meaning is it neither `NORTH`, `SOUTH`, `EAST`, or `WEST` (case sensitive). This is causing an infinite iteration between `cycle` and `dropwhile`

If you read the documentation for `itertools`, [dropwhile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle)

> Make an iterator that drops elements from the iterable as long as the predicate is true; afterwards, returns every element

First, given `dropwhile` drops elements as long as the predicate is true, it will finally stop once it's reaches a false value and then return the remaining element. Second, the usage of [cycle](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) generates a repeating iterator

> Make an iterator returning elements from the iterable and saving a copy of each. When the iterable is exhausted, return elements from the saved copy. Repeats indefinitely

Since the value of `direction` does not exist within `directions`, `dropwhile` is looking through an iterator of infinite length and never reaching a case that breaks it